# Angular+ Material: matdrawer overlapping mattoolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, toolbar, drawer

I am trying to build a drawer that contains a mattoolbar, anfd that would overlap the main toolbar of my application.

For some reason, I am not able to move the drawer above in the component tree. And I am looking for a css only solution.

I actually don't get the reason why my drawer's toolbar is not shown on top of the main toolbar.

Here is a stackblitz showing the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/drawer-overlapping-toolbar?file=app%2Fapp.css

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use sidenav instead of drawer.

The sidenav accepts a `fixedInViewport` parameter that allows it.

I changed the stackblitz with the working version.